# laravel set checked to checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, validation, fetch-api

The user select a product and then using the fetch api of javascript I'm getting his qualities and then the user check the checkboxes to register this in a pivot table:

[image]

All is ok, but there is another inputs in the form tha will be validated and when one fails, the webpage is reloaded, I can save the old product and fetch again all his qualities but I'm unable of check the old checkboxes.

This my current code:

```
  //Fetch again the qualities of the product after the validation.

  var oldProduct= ( ('{{ old("product") }}' !='') ? '{{ old("product") }}' : '-1');
    if(oldProduct!=-1){
        fetch("{{route('admin.searchQualitiesByProduct')}}",{
        method : 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({product : oldProduct}),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
        }
    }).then(response =>{
        return response.json()
    }).then( data =>{
        var checkboxes = "";           
        data.lista.forEach(function(calidad) {
            var isChecked = '{{ @if(is_array(old("qualitiesProductCheckbox")) && in_array("'+calidad.id+'", old("qualitiesProductCheckbox"))) checked @endif }}';
            
           alert(isChecked);
            checkboxes +=  '<input type="checkbox" '+isChecked+' name="qualitiesProductCheckbox[]"  value="'+calidad.id+'">&nbsp;Calidad: <label>'+calidad.name+'</label><br>';  
            
       });

    document.getElementById("_calidades").innerHTML = checkboxes;
    }).catch(error =>console.error(error));

    }
```

The code: `var isChecked = '@if(is_array(old("qualitiesProductCheckbox")) && in_array("'+calidad.id+'", old("qualitiesProductCheckbox"))) checked @endif';` always returns a 'empty' string and never the value 'checked'.. and for that reason I'm unable of auto-check the checkboxes after the page was reloaded.

What I'm doing wrong in that validation inside the javascript code? Any idea guys for fix this problem I will appreciate it.
Thanks so much.

**Bug Fixed**

`var isChecked = '@if(is_array(old("qualitiesProductCheckbox")) && in_array("'+calidad.id+'", old("qualitiesProductCheckbox"))) checked @endif';` should be inside of `{{ }}` :

`var isChecked = '{{ @if(is_array(old("qualitiesProductCheckbox")) && in_array("'+calidad.id+'", old("qualitiesProductCheckbox"))) checked @endif }}';`

However laravel now throwed an error:

```
Syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: C:\laragon\www\simbiosis\resources\views\buyer\edit.blade.php)
```

The error is inside of the fixed bug. ``var isChecked = '{{ @if(......`

Comment: whats inside `old("qualitiesProductCheckbox")`, also show an example of what you are getting old data after validation

Comment: Hi bro, sorry I can't get your idea, but when the page is loaded for the first time there isn't any checkbox, checkbox appear when I choise a product from the select, then if I send the form and is somthing wrong because of the validation, I'm getting again the qualities of the selected product as I showed in the code of my post.. I have fixed a bug because the code of the `var isChecked="...."` should be inside of braces/keys `var isChecked="{{ ... }}"` I fixed it but laravel throwed this error `syntax error, unexpected '<'` . Please bro if you have any Idea for fix this I will appreciate